# Чтение json API

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, cross-domain, cross-origin

Есть JSON. Читаю его функцией fetch:

```
let response = await fetch('https://rutube.ru/api/video/b07639337aa57ce56578bbb9e40e0102/', {mode: 'no-cors'});
console.log(response.body);
```

Но в ответ получаю null. Как всё-таки получить JSON?

Comment: `await response.json()`

Comment: Всё равно null :-(

Comment: А что показывают devtools по самому́ сетевому запросу (какой код ответа, и что приходит _браузеру_ в теле ответа)? И что по этому поводу говорят бэкэндеры rutube?

Comment: А, ну вы же прописали no-cors, это запрещает читать ответ

Comment: @andreymal наоборот. Без него ответ вообще не принимается

Comment: @IvanU с ним тоже ответ не принимается. Вы не имеете права читать ответы с чужих сайтов, это специально сделано ради безопасности

Comment: @yar85 ответ 200, в ответе "Filed to load response data". По поводу бэкэндеров не понял

Comment: @andreymal и как быть?

Comment: @yar85 тип ответа — opaque, браузер в принципе никак и никогда не даст его прочитать

Comment: _«По поводу бэкэндеров не понял»_ - это я так толсто намекаю, что апишка похоже не совсем паблик, и она вполне может не хотеть разговаривать с незнакомцами (помимо реферера может проверять например куки, какой-либо токен в заголовке, и т.д. - стоит внимательнее изучить "родные" запросы).

Comment: @andreymal, точно, `no-cors` ведь... с этим я тупанул.

Comment: @andreymal, получается что если сервер предполагает CORS и не хочет общаться без оного, то автор никак не сможет получить ответ с "левого" хоста, правильно? //Без проксирования запросов, в смысле.

Comment: @yar85 а как понять, что сервер не хочет no-cors? Какие заголовки об этом говорят?

Comment: Насколько знаю, об этом говорит заголовок ответа `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (он присутствует, когда запрос отправлен с заголовком `Origin`, добавляемый браузером автоматически). Но вообще я не оч разбираюсь в запросах к чужим серверам, т.к. обычно работаю с "дружественными" серверами (той компании где работаю, и публичных апи) - поэтому, лучше проверь загуглив это.

Comment: @yar85 сервер принимает такие заголовки:
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,X-Ally,cache,X-CSRFToken,jwt-without-personal-data`

Comment: Видимо, проблема в том, что сервер вообще не отправляет  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Не понятно почему, ведь это открытое API

Comment: @IvanU, _«сервер вообще не отправляет `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`»_ - значит, он не разрешает запросы из других origin'ов (следовательно, это не публичный апи).